# (Python MySQLdb) when trying to insert UTF-8 into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8

I cannot find a solution.
Can you help me with this question please?

```
    dic={'username':u'\uc774\ud55c\ub098','userid':u'david007', 'nation':u'\ub300\ud55c\ubbfc\uad6d'}
    c=MySQLdb.connect(host=ddb['host'],user=ddb['user'],passwd=ddb['passwd'],db=ddb['db'], use_unicode=True, charset="utf8")
    s=c.cursor()
    sql="INSERT INTO "+db+" "+col+" VALUES "+str(tuple(dic.values()))
    s.execute(sql)

    "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''\\uc774\\ud55 ... at line 1")

    print sql
    INSERT INTO user_tb (username, userid, nation) VALUES (u'\uc774\ud55c\ub098', u'david007', u'\ub300\ud55c\ubbfc\uad6d')
```

And the error is:

Comment: That is not even valid Python code. Can you include the cursor `.execute()` call as stated in your code? It looks like you are mixing up your python string literal syntax in there but I want to see this is detail.

Comment: add single quotes to values maybe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a parametrised query:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO " + db + " " + col + " VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
s.execute(sql, dic.values())
```

When you simply concatenate the tuple to your query, the `u` prefix of the unicode strings will make those strings invalid SQL. With parameters MySQLdb, will do the right thing with the parameter replacement (i.e. encoding the unicode strings to a byte representation) and generate valid SQL.

Anyway as a general principle you should **always** use parameters in your queries to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: user1161599@ You did put Python escaped codes like `u'\uc774\ud55c\ub098'` into SQL, but the database does not understant Python type of escaping and `u` prefix. Note that "Perdo" correctly does not use parsing of strings into SQL string at all because it would be vulnerable to SQL injection attack. He uses parameters.